# Plot colored spectral lines using spectral line data?

Tags: graphics, curated-data, chemistry

Suppose I've retrieved spectral line data for an element, as so:

```
hydrogenSpectralLines =SpectralLineData[EntityClass["AtomicLine", {"Hydrogen", 1}]];
```

From that, I can extract only the visible lines, and their frequencies, using

`EntityValue[x,EntityProperty["AtomicLine", "Frequency"]]`

So in the end I guess what I have are really just a bunch of "Quantity" objects.

So, I've filtered for *just the visible* ones, and I want to visualize them as they might appear if I actually put a camera in a spectrometer. Like [this image from Wikipedia, made by Jan Homann](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Visible_spectrum_of_hydrogen.jpg):

[image: example]

Should I just use Rectangle objects, or is there a "higher-level" way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example for that for [`SpectralLineData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpectralLineData.html): [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpectralLineData.html#1924903400).

```
hydrogenSpectralLines = 
  SpectralLineData[
   EntityClass[
    "AtomicLine", {"Hydrogen", 1}], {Quantity[400, "Nanometers"], 
    Quantity[750, "Nanometers"]}];

hydrogenLineLengths = 
  QuantityMagnitude[
   SpectralLineData[hydrogenSpectralLines, "Wavelength"], 
   "Nanometers"];

Graphics[{ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][#], Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}]} & /@
   hydrogenLineLengths, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {True, False}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/3, Background -> Black, 
 FrameLabel -> Quantity[None, "Nanometers"]]
```

[image: hydrogen spectral lines]

Comment: Oops, right in the help file! Thanks for pointing this out.